# Having count() greater than average of

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to resolve the following SQL query which it's supposed to show the equipment data that had more problems this year than the average amount of problems of all equipments in the past year and i'm a little bit stuck with it.

I've come up with this so far:

```
select e.equipment_id ,
       e.equipment_name ,
       e.equipment_serialnum ,
       e.equipment_descrip
from equipment e ,
     problems  p
where e.equipment_id       = p.equipment_id
  and year( problem_date ) = year( getdate() )
group by e.equipment_id   ,
         e.equipment_name ,
         e.equipment_serialnum ,
         e.equipment_descrip
having count(p.problem_id) > ( select avg( pnumber )
                               from ( SELECT p1.problem_id ,
                                             COUNT( p1.problem_id ) AS pnumber
                                      FROM problems  p1
                                      JOIN equipment e1 ON e1.equipment_id = p1.equipment_id
                                                       and year( p1.problem_date ) = 2013
                                      GROUP BY p1.problem_id
                                    )
```

but it's not working. This is the structure of the tables involved in the query

```
problems
(
  problem_id      integer  not null identity(1,1)
  equipment_id    integer  not null,
  user_id         integer  not null,
  problem_date    datetime not null,
  problem_descrip varchar(255)
)

equipment
(
  equipment_id        integer    not null identity(1,1) ,
  equipment_type_cod  char(20)   not null ,
  equipment_bought    datetime   not null ,
  equipment_available datetime   ,
  equipment_serialnum char(20)   ,
  equipment_name    varchar(255) ,
  equipment_descrip varchar(255)
)
```

I appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: When you say 'not working', do you mean you are getting unexpected results, or a SQL error?

Comment: Just glancing at the code you posted, it's missing a final closing parenthesis.

Comment: Matt thanks for the help, i tried a closing parenthesis but it still doesn't work.

Comment: My guess is that by "not working" you're getting any equipment that ever had 2 or more problems in the last year? Also, you need to alias the subquery, so between the last two parens (the one you say you added and the last one here) you'll need a table alias.

Comment: it's working! thanks everyone for taking time to help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subselect needs a table name

```
( select avg( pnumber )
    from ( SELECT p1.problem_id ,
             COUNT( p1.problem_id ) AS pnumber
      FROM problems  p1
      JOIN equipment e1 ON e1.equipment_id = p1.equipment_id
                       and year( p1.problem_date ) = 2013
      GROUP BY p1.problem_id
    ) x
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, lets create our schema:

```
create table dbo.equipment
(
  equipment_id        integer      not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,
  equipment_type_cod  char(20)     not null ,
  equipment_bought    datetime     not null ,
  equipment_available datetime              ,
  equipment_serialnum char(20)              ,
  equipment_name      varchar(255)          ,
  equipment_descrip   varchar(255)          ,
)
go

create table dbo.problems
(
  problem_id      integer      not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,
  equipment_id    integer      not null foreign key references dbo.equipment( equipment_id ) ,
  user_id         integer      not null ,
  problem_date    datetime     not null ,
  problem_descrip varchar(255)          ,
)
go
```

It's often helpful to decompose our problem into smaller, discrete chunks. SQL Server's `with` clause is helpful here, as it provides a convenient way to define names virtual tables:

```
with
--
-- a 1-row table containing the starting date for the previous, current and next years
--
year_start as (
  select prev = convert(date,datename(year,dateadd(year, -1 , current_timestamp))) ,
         curr = convert(date,datename(year,dateadd(year,  0 , current_timestamp))) ,
         next = convert(date,datename(year,dateadd(year, +1 , current_timestamp)))
) ,
--
-- the count of problems per unit over the previous year. This
-- uses a left join to include those pieces of equipment that had no problems.
-- Depending on you requirement, you might want to change that to an inner join.
--
prev_year_problems as (
  select equipment_id = e.equipment_id ,
         problem_cnt  = coalesce( p.problems , 0 )
  from dbo.equipment e
  left join ( select equipment_id = p.equipment_id ,
                     problems     = count(*)
              from       dbo.problems p
              cross join year_start   y
              where p.problem_date >= y.prev
                and p.problem_date <  y.curr
              group by p.equipment_id
            ) p on p.equipment_id = e.equipment_id
) ,
--
-- the count of problems per unit in the current year, up to the current date.
-- This is essentially identical to the previous CTE, with the exception of
-- the boundaries of the desired date range.
--
curr_year_problems as (
  select equipment_id = e.equipment_id ,
         problem_cnt  = coalesce( p.problems , 0 )
  from dbo.equipment e
  left join ( select equipment_id = p.equipment_id ,
                     problems     = count(*)
              from       dbo.problems p
              cross join year_start   y
              where p.problem_date >= y.curr
                and p.problem_date <  y.next
              group by p.equipment_id
            ) p on p.equipment_id = e.equipment_id
) ,
--
-- Here, we roll the previous year's problem counts up and summarize them into
-- a single row table containing the mean number of problems per unit over the year.
--
previous_year_summary as (
  select mean_problems_per_unit = avg( t.problem_cnt )
  from prev_year_problems t
)
--
-- Finally, we select the rows from the equipment table that meet the defined
-- criteria
--
select e.* ,
       curr_year_problems_to_date       = cyp.problem_cnt ,
       prev_year_mean_problems_per_unit = ps.mean_problems_per_unit
from dbo.equipment         e
join curr_year_problems    cyp on cyp.equipment_id = e.equipment_id
join previous_year_summary ps  on cyp.problem_cnt > ps.mean_problems_per_unit
```